# Convert mmddyy to YYYY-MM-DD in expression task in SSIS

Tags: date, ssis, ssis-2016, derived-column, ssis-2017

I'm trying to use the below code to convert data from

```
'010118' to '2018-01-01'

(DT_DATE)(RIGHT(DATE,2) + LEFT(DATE,2) + SUBSTRING(DATE,3,2))
```

When I run this in SSIS i'm getting conversion error

> An error occurred while attempting to perform a type cast.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution for this using the below code

```
"20" + RIGHT(DATE,2) + "-" + LEFT(DATE,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING(DATE,3,2)
```